# How to SetDlgItemText a std::vector?

Tags: c++, mfc

I'm learning so if the code is terribly written, you know why.

I have a simple MFC dialog that calculates the length of the hypotenuse in a right triangle.

```
double calchyp( int x, int y )
{
    //C^2 = A^2 + B^2
    double z2 = ( x * x ) + ( y * y );
    double z = pow( z2, 0.5 );
    return z;
}

std::vector<CString> history;

void CMFCApplication8Dlg::OnBnClickedButtonc()
{
    CString A;
    CString B;

    double a1;
    double b1;

    GetDlgItemText( IDC_A, A );
    GetDlgItemText( IDC_B, B );

    a1 = _wtof( A );
    b1 = _wtof( B );

    double C1 = calchyp( a1, b1 );
    CString result;
    result.Format( L"%4.2lf", C1 );

    SetDlgItemText( IDC_C, result );
    history.push_back( result );
    SetDlgItemText( IDC_History, history );
}
```

As you can tell from the last 2 lines, I'm trying to save the results in a vector, and then display that vector in `IDC_History` as the history of my results.

My compiler (Visual Studio) is underlining the history in the last line and giving me an error, my compiler is in German so I can't translate the error accurately, but it is close to this:

> Converting from "std::vector, std::allocator" to "LPCTSTR" is not available.

Comment: Perhaps you should use another control, instead of a plain text control? Like a *list* control that can contain multiple elements?

Comment: As for the error, `history` is a *vector* of strings. The `SetDlgItemText` function is to set a *single* string.

Comment: What kind of control is `IDC_History`?

Comment: IDC_History is Edit Control,  
right now I'm try what the other user suggested with the list contol.

Comment: An edit control is definitly not appropriate for a history. Best use a list box or maybe a drop list and use `AddString` to add the result. Then you don't need a vector at all, the control takes care of storing the strings.

Comment: Go to your IDE's *Tools* menu, select *Options*. In the dialog select the *Environment* -> *International Settings*, and pick English as the Language. No more guessing as to what an error message would be translated to.

Comment: Offtopic: It is documented somewhere you should use UPPER CASE as identifiers, like `IDC_HISTORY`

Comment: @sergiol It's just a convention to use uppercase. Not required. Control identifiers are macros and by consistently using uppercase it helps to recognize that.  MFC itself uses all uppercase for identifiers so identifiers.